# What's an easy algorithm to check for triangle-freeness?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms, proof-explanation, computational-complexity, extremal-combinatorics

This is from a text that I'm reading.

[image]

By "query the status of any pair of vertices", I assume the author means "to check whether the two vertices are adjacent"? From there how do they go about checking for triangle-freeness? What would the order of the number of steps required be?

Answer (score 1):

There are only $\Theta(n^2)$ pairs of vertices in the graph, so you can query *every* pair; then you simply check every triplet in the graph to see if they form a triangle.

Comment: Such an algorithm would then require $\Theta(n^6)$ steps, instead of $\Theta(n^2)$?

Comment: @ensbana It would take $\Theta(n^3)$ *steps*, but presumably you can remember the result of your queries, so for fixed vertices $a, b$ and variable vertex $c$, to check triangle-freeness of $(a, b, c)$ you only need to query $(a, b)$ once. This gives $\Theta(n^2)$ *queries*.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A$ be the adjacency matrix of the graph. Then the graph is triangle free if and only if $tr(A^3)=0$. This relies on the fact that the powers of the adjacency matrix count the number of paths of that length.

While this is concise and looks easy I doubt this is a fast way to check triangle-freeness for a large graph.

Comment: Still a nice way to look at it :^). [Reference](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication_algorithm) for matrix multiplication complexity for the curious among us.